# How to create a custom macro function to add a cell value which is separated by “+” or “-”

Tags: excel, vba

In Microsoft Excel, I have a sheet like below

[image]

I want to make a VBA function that will calculate the Total Amount.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to active your requirements

```
' Function for adding a cell value that is separated by + symbole
Function AddCellValue(Rng As Range) As Variant
    AddCellValue = Evaluate(Application.Substitute(Rng, "+", "+"))
End Function
```

Comment: You are really awesome. This is i am looking.